# Strophe cannot connect to Facebook through BOSH server

Tags: xmpp, strophe

It works perfectly for Openfire Server. If anyone can suggest what is the way out to connect to Facebook through Strophe. We are using Punjab server as a standalone BOSH connection manager.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook closed their XMPP chat API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat

Comment: Hangout is replacing Google Talk. Hangout does not support XMPP.